# getting value of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to see if a value exists in a JSON object and if it exists the value should be placed in the DOM .

in my example I'm having problems getting access to the value that is paired with a name of "value" in the array arr.

In the end result I would like  the user to type text in the textbox and when they select an option and the option box closes the value should be put in the placed div. before the value is placed it has to check if the value exists in the array so gibberish wont be placed in the placed element.

```
    var arr = [ 
        {value : "c++", price: "5.69"},
        {value : "php", price: "5.69"},
        {value : "coldfusion", price: "5.69"},
        {value : "javascript", price: "5.69"},
        {value : "asp", price: "5.69"},
        {value : "ruby", price: "5.69"},
     ];
     // alert(arr.value)
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({

    source  : arr,
  close : function(event, ui){
    var val = $('input#autocomplete').val();
     //Definite problem[index needed?]
    if ($.inArray(val,arr.value) > -1) {
       $('.placed').html(val);
    }

  }
});
```

I just started learning about JSON and Im not sure about checking to see if the val exists in this type of array. so If you could help me that would be great.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/A4eH8/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.inArray` on a plain array, but you have here an array of objects. So try using `$.grep` to get all the matches.

```
 close: function (event, ui) {
            var val = $('input#autocomplete').val();
            var res = $.grep(arr, function (o) { //Will give you all the matches
                  return o.value.indexOf(val) > -1;
            });

            if (res.length) {
                $('.placed').html(val);
            }

        }
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsLx8/)

But it seems like you just want to see if the match is there or not so in that case use just `$.each`

```
    close: function (event, ui) {
        var val = $('input#autocomplete').val();
        var match = false;
        $.each(arr, function (_, o) {
            if (o.value === val) {
                match = true;
                return false; //break the look once you find a match
            }
        });
        if (match) {
            $('.placed').html(val);
        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ReYbQ/)**

Comment: Thanks for your response but maybe I was unclear when the dropdown box is closed by clicking anywhere else on the page the text that was input into the box should not be placed into the placed div if it does not match the value in the array exactly. so in your example when I type p in the box for php then close the box nothing should show up in the "placed" div but in your example  "p" is in the div there should be no p since p was not in the array it is "php". can you fix that when you get a chance?

Comment: @user2537537 I think you did not check the second example and demo link in my answer...

Comment: im checking the second 1 now. I din't see it before I wrote that

Comment: @user2537537 Yeah the first one i was thinking you wanted a like match then i realized and added the second option.

Comment: K it works. thanks, but can you please explain what the underscore is used for in the first param of the $.each function(_, o)

Comment: @user2537537 haa.. Thats the index and we are not using it so just gave the name as "_"